# SQL Server Strings and Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have an annoying issue with Microsoft trying the be too clever again, when I query my database and a value such as **2/2** is returned in a `nvarchar` field it automatically decides this is a date and should instead be **02-Feb** which is no fun when its the first line of an address!

This is in SQL Server Management Studio.

Any Ideas?

My Code is as follows:

```
SELECT LTRIM(ISNULL(FlatNo+case when LEN(FLATNO) < 1 then '' else ' ' end,' ')
+ISNULL(Building+case when LEN(Building) < 1 then '' else ' ' end,' ')
+ISNULL(Line1+case when LEN(Line2) < 1 then '' else CHAR(10)+CHAR(13) end,' ')
+ISNULL(Line2+case when LEN(Line3) < 1 then '' else CHAR(10)+CHAR(13) end,' ')
+ISNULL(Line3,' ')) AS MailingAddress
FROM [Address]
```

This issue is cropping up in the first field, 'FlatNo'

The value in the field being converted is '2/2'

Comment: It will not automatically cast this to a date unless you are `UNION`-ing it with a date column or something.

Comment: Can you show your actual code or explain better? `SELECT '02/02/2008'` doesn't get converted to a date for me for example.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in either the Editor window nor the results pane (in text or grid mode) with SSMS 2008. You need to add more details of a way to reproduce this issue. TBH, it sounds more like the behaviour of Excel.

Comment: that's strange... If you run a `select N'2/2' as test` do you get the same "conversion"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all apps that have touched the data! Excel converts dates in the manor described above, this was my issue.

Thanks to all of you who helped!

Comment: Yet another reason to not let Excel ever touch your data!